# Be sure to Maintain Test cases Chronology> Selenium Page Factory> Element initialization leads to "No such Element Exception" under POM model

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects, page-factory

Alright, so below issue is what I was trying to resolve until I see the fault was not in my code but in Test CLASS. Not deleting the question because it might help someone if they encounter the somewhat same issue.

**Make sure your test cases (Used TestNG in this case) are written in chronological order or their order should be properly defined.**

*So after above's note following was what I was facing:*

My code is unable to locate web elements when Selenium Page Factory is initializing WebElements which is declared in my Framework's Base Class.

The element reference is correct and the code works properly with usual

```
 FindElement(By.cssSelector("locator"))
```

Alright, this problem might look repetitive but no answer in other questions could help me.
I have tried implicit/Explicit waits; I tried accommodating everything in single class using PageFactory but nothing seems to be working.

I've created a simple TestNG Framework for simple "Google Search"
where the GoogleSearchAction class is extending a 'BaseClass' in latter Elements are initialized using Page Factory. 
Below is the code for Base Class:

```
/*Base Class:*/

public class BaseActions {
WebDriver driver;
       public BaseActions(WebDriver driver) {
           this.driver = driver;
           PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
         }

       public void launchApplication(String baseUrl)  {
             System.out.println("URL:" + baseUrl);
             driver.get(baseUrl);
        }

      public void end_All_The_Browser_session() {
             driver.quit();
       }

}
```

Now the following is the Sub Action Class

```
public class Test_Google_Search_Action extends BaseActions {

     @FindBy(css = "input[name='q']")
     private WebElement inputBox_TextField;

     public Test_Google_Search_Action(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
      }

     public void Navigate_search_Page() throws FileNotFoundException, 
         InterruptedException {  
         inputBox_TextField.sendKeys(yamlReader.getValue("seacrhText_1"));
         inputBox_TextField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
      }
  }
```

And following is the StackTrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to 
locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='q']"}
(Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86) 
 *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=input[name='q']}
```

Just Restating: 
The locator is correct and the code works fine If don't use Page Factory.

I am pretty sure it is a silly mistake I just can not pinpoint it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume there is some part of your initialization  that google is loaded when you get to that line?

Comment: you mean to say, Google is not properly loaded by the time web elements get initialized?
if so, I have tried adding dynamic as well as hard waits nothing happens, same error.

Comment: OK.. Isn't `super(driver)` what actually calls `initElements()`?  So you are defining that variable before/outside of that class.  Why don't you try it inside that class right after `super(driver)`

Comment: I did try what you are saying, now I have put initElements() within the action class. It's the same error. 
Also, I have tried to print the element 



>>> System.out.println("WebElement::"+ inputBox_TextField); and got



>>> WebElement::Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.cssSelector: input[name='q']'

Comment: The core problem seems to be that you are trying to interact with the element before navigating to the google search page.  Can you show us the code of the test that uses this page object?

Comment: @Ardesco Exactly that was the problem. I missed out on validating the chronological order of tests in the test class. 
Felt like not removing the question from here, just in case somebody else forgets in keeping this check.
I fixed my test class and used the exact same code written above and it worked fine.
Thanks

Comment: @SSabharwal, it would probably be useful to update the question to make it more obvious that you have found the problem and what the solution was for future reference.  I suspect a lot of people will not go through the comments and just scan through the answers instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove PageFactory init from BaseActions and put it in the constructor of Test_Google_Search_Action.

Comment: Wired working fine on my machine. Please check this https://github.com/tanuj-vishnoi/questions_55408215/invitations